# How to get the percentage of multiple input fields in every row using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of two inputs then percentage total, my problem is I have 4 sets of columns with the same input fields process but have different percentages total in every total. Here my sample HTML in tabular for.

```
<td>Management</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-1"" name="local[]" value="">1 2</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-2" name="non_local[]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light p-total" name="local_percentage[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="employ_position_id[]" value="1">
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-1" name="local[]" value="">1 2</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-2" name="non_local[]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light p-total" name="local_percentage[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="employ_position_id[]" value="1">
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-1"" name="local[]" value="">1 2</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-2" name="non_local[]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light p-total" name="local_percentage[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="employ_position_id[]" value="1">
</td>
```

Here's my javascript code that I'll trying to improve. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
$('.percent-1').on('input', function() {
    console.log("Input 1");
    calculate();
 });
 $('.percent-2').on('input', function() {
     calculate();
 });
 function calculate(){
     var pPos = parseInt($('.percent-1').val()); 
     var pEarned = parseInt($('.percent-2').val());
     var perc="";
     if(isNaN(pPos) || isNaN(pEarned)){
         perc=" ";
     }else{
     perc = ((pEarned/pPos) * 100);
 }
  $('.p-total').val(perc);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve the result with `index` as key.

You could get all the elements with same class using [**querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method like,

```
const input1 = document.querySelectorAll('.percent-1');
const input2 = document.querySelectorAll('.percent-2');
const total = document.querySelectorAll('.p-total');
```

`querySelectorAll()` will give the array of elements, so you could iterate and include [**addEventListener()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on each element then pass the `index` of the inputed element to `calculate` function like,

```
input1.forEach((el,index) => {
  el.addEventListener('input',() => {
     calculate(index);
  })
})
```

Then with the index, you can get the value from the respective input like,

```
var pPos = parseInt(input1[index].value);
```

Same scenario for `percent-2` and `total` as well.

The **working snippet** as follows,

```js
 function calculate(index){
     var pPos = parseInt(input1[index].value); 
     var pEarned = parseInt(input2[index].value);
     var perc="";
     if(isNaN(pPos) || isNaN(pEarned)){
         perc=" ";
     }else{
     perc = ((pEarned/pPos) * 100);
 }
  total[index].value = perc;
} 


const input1 = document.querySelectorAll('.percent-1');
const input2 = document.querySelectorAll('.percent-2');
const total = document.querySelectorAll('.p-total');

input1.forEach((el,index) => {
  el.addEventListener('input',() => {
     calculate(index);
  })
})

input2.forEach((el,index) => {
  el.addEventListener('input',() => {
     calculate(index);
  })
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Management</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-1"" name="local[]" value="">1 2</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-2" name="non_local[]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light p-total" name="local_percentage[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="employ_position_id[]" value="1">
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-1" name="local[]" value="">1 2</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-2" name="non_local[]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light p-total" name="local_percentage[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="employ_position_id[]" value="1">
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-1"" name="local[]" value="">1 2</td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light percent-2" name="non_local[]" value=""></td>
<td><input type="text" class="input-light p-total" name="local_percentage[]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="employ_position_id[]" value="1">
</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer with an explanation, a bit lost here but now it's working already.
I have a follow-up question, How can I get now the grand total at the end of the column? like a grand total of all the inputs in the bottom, thanks.

Comment: @dev5, Can you look at here https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/BaoQGzO for grand total scenario..

Comment: Thanks ill try to get the total of by column as well, like percent-1, percent-2 have different total then get the final percentage of percent-1 and percent-2.

Comment: @dev5, yUP , I totally leave that to you to calculate grand total as per your wish.. But hope you got the idea in how to display the grand total from the link provided..

Comment: Thanks, mate much appreciated still learning the js language here.

Comment: Hi @Maniraj Murugan, sorry to ask again i cant make it the grand total in every column, i put in input fields all the total in percentTotal-1, percentTotal-2 and pg-total, then do the same calculation when onchange event happens in all percentTotal-1, percentTotal-2 and pg-total.

Comment: @dev5, Sorry I couldn't get you.. Can you explain little bit clear??

Comment: I add another sets of table row in the bottom like my input fields, but now i label it like total-percent-1 total-percent-2 and pg-total same as p-total, but the percentage of total-percent-1 and total-percent-2. And hanppens when onchange even trigger for the two total(total-percent-1 and total-percent-2). which is calcated total of (percent-1 and percent-2).

Comment: input1Total.forEach((el,index) => {
    el.addEventListener('change',() => {
      calculateGrand(index);
    })
  })
  input2Total.forEach((el,index) => {
    el.addEventListener('change',() => {
      calculateGrand(index);
    })
  })

Comment: @dev5, Please create your issue in https://codepen.io/pen/ and share the link for better understanding..

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation @Maniraj Murugan, here's my codepen sample code https://codepen.io/dev5/pen/oNjYOLP

Comment: @dev5, Are you mean to say that grand total (in first row) is not working in the codepen you provided??

Comment: i add another row HR,  i mean each of column have a individual total. that based on the Management and HR. Thanks

Comment: Yes you have added another row and when you input into first input and second input, it shows the result in third input box  (In second row) as per your example.. What is your requirement here?/

Comment: @dev5, Or else please add some screenshot of your expected result .. Else open new question..

Comment: Yes, now i trying to achieve is to calcute also the the first input of management and the first input of HR then put the total below except my first example that getting the percentage.

Comment: The idea is the same but the two input fields in the total row are the sum of management input1 and input2 and hr input1 and input2, then same calculation of percentage.

Comment: @dev5, Okay based on my understanding you need to calculate the the last total row vertically for first two inputs and the sum (addition) of these two inputs needs to be in third(final) input box.. Am I right??

Comment: Yes, @Maniraj Murugan the third input in the row total is the percentage of two sums.